# Limit to only one result in react?

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React and any tips will help.

Using the code below I am pulling the authors name and link location. The info is to be displayed on a search results page. I want only one author to show per article (even if there are multiple authors for that article).

```
{hit.authors.map((authors, index) => (
  <div className="author-search">
    <span>By: </span>
    <Link to={`/authors/${authors.slug}`}>{authors.name}</Link>
  </div>
))}
```

**The question:** How do you limit the results to one instance if there are multiple authors listed for one article?

**What is happening:**

Article Title
John Doe /
Jane Doe /
Johnny Doe

**What I want (regardless of actual number of author results):**

Article Title
John Doe

Comment: Take that out of `.map` and use `authors[0]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use a map, simply access the first element of the array:

```js
const author = hit.authors[0];
return (
  <div className="author-search">
    <span>By: </span>
    <Link to={`/authors/${author.slug}`}>{author.name}</Link>
  </div>
)
```